# Notebook output in single place

Tags: front-end, cells

I find that cell output below each cell terrible for organizational purposes.  Is there another way to display the output of each cell?

Answer (score 2):

You can find endless ways to get what you have asked for looking Help for `CreateDocument` or `NotebookWrite`:

```
myNb = CreateDocument[1 + 1];
NotebookWrite[myNb, 2 + 2];
```

Another possibility, as example, is:

```
fileOut = "example.txt";
streamOut = OpenWrite[fileOut];
Write[streamOut, OutputForm[Log[1/x]]];
Close[streamOut];
```

Can you, please, describe your needs in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying an example in the documentation to [$Pre](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html), one can save all output and then process it as desired.  Begin by defining.

```
SetAttributes[saveoutputs, HoldAll];
outputs = {};
saveoutputs[new_] := (outputs = {outputs, HoldForm[new]}; new);
$Post = saveoutputs;
```

Then create some output, for instance,

```
r = 3.2
(* 3.2 *)

area = Pi r^2
(* 32.1699 *)
```

A calculation with no output

```
noout = E^2;
```

Two lines in a single cell

```
Sqrt[3]
%^2
(* Sqrt[3] *)
(* 3 *)
```

`Solve` an equation

```
Solve[x^5 - x + 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 2]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 3]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 4]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 5]}} *)
```

Finally, turn off the output-saving.

```
$Post =.
```

All the output now is in `outputs`, as can be seen from

```
Flatten[outputs] // TableForm
```

[image]

Note that each element of `outputs` remains in `HoldForm`.  A user wishing to use parts of `outputs` can copy the desired line and paste it as input.  Usually, it also is possible to apply `ReleaseHold` to the desired element, as in

```
ReleaseHold[Flatten[outputs][[7]]]
(* {{x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 2]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 3]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 4]}, 
    {x -> Root[1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 5]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change this at the `Notebook` level try setting `CellEvaluationFunction` at the stylesheet level to evaluate and then return `Null`.

i.e., evaluate the following in the stylesheet editing page

```
CellPrint@
  Cell[
    StyleData["Notebook"],
    CellEvaluationFunction->(someContext`$evalFunction@ToExpression@#;&)
    ]
```

The `ToExpression` is necessary as the function takes the `BoxData` argument of the cell. The  `` someContext` ``  is useful because otherwise `evalFunction` will be tagged as `` $CellContext`evalFunction `` and so will, I believe, depend on the context of the cell (usually `` Global` ``). Just makes it a little bit cleaner.

Now whatever you set as `` someContext`$evalFunction `` will be applied to the output of the evaluation for any cell in the notebook but no output cells will be returned.

Here's an example pushing the outputs onto the end of a new document:

```
CellPrint@
  Cell[
    StyleData["Notebook"],
    CellEvaluationFunction->
      (If[!MatchQ[
             NotebookInformation@betterFormatting`Private`nb,_List],
         betterFormatting`Private`nb=
           CreateDocument[{},
             WindowTitle->"Output Notebook",
             System`ClosingSaveDialog->False]
         ];
       SelectionMove[betterFormatting`Private`nb,After,Notebook];
       NotebookWrite[betterFormatting`Private`nb,
         Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@ToExpression@#,"Output"]
         ];&)
    ]
```